# Find the rotation of a quad (4 points, planar)

Tags: python, 3d, maya

How can I find the rotation of a quad? (it is planar)
Lets say there is an unknown randomly rotated quad like this:

[image]

The final rotation values should output something like this:
[image]

I have found the first vector (y), but not sure how to finish this...

```
vec1 = pt2 - pt1
vec2 = pt3 - pt1

cross1 = vec1.cross(vec2).normal()
angle = pm.angleBetween(euler=1, v1=(0,-1,0), v2=cross1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy enough to get the matrix that represents that orientation; you can work backwards from that to rotations.

If you're sure the quad is planar, you can just use the face normal (which should be equivalent to any of the vertex-face normals).  If not, you can derive it from the cross vectors as you tried to do in your example.  If the geometry is really planar the results will be the same.

To assemble the matrix, you just need three vectors that are all normal to each other.  Using the XYZ order implied by your image, it would work like this:

```
import pymel.core as pm
from pymel.core.datatypes import Matrix, Vector, TransformationMatrix

points = [Vector(pm.xform('pPlane1.vtx[%i]' % i, q=True, t=True, ws=True))  for i in range(4)]

local_x = (points[1] - points[0]).normal()
local_z = (points[2] - points[0]).normal()
local_y = local_x.cross(local_z).normal()
```

For good measure, get the centroid of the quad too so we can make it the location of the matrix we'll create - it's easier for debugging:

```
centroid = sum(points) / 4.0
```

Now we construct the actual matrix.  To make it clearer, here's a slightly
long-winded way to put it together:

```
 matrix = TransformationMatrix (
               local_x.x, local_x.y, local_x.z, 0,
               local_y.x, local_y.y, local_y.z, 0,
               local_z.x, local_z.y, local_z.z, 0,
               centroid.x, centroid.y, centroid.z, 1
     )
```

Note that you want the `pymel.datatypes.TransformationMatrix`, which is a specialization of the `Matrix` class that handles things like euler and quaternion conversions for you.

To makes sure this was done right, you can make a locator and set it's position using the matrix.  You should get the same arrangement in your image:

```
locator = pm.spaceLocator()
pm.xform(locator, m=matrix, ws=True)
```

If you're working in units other than centimeters you might need to multiply `centroid` by a conversion factor; ie, if you're in meters you'd multiply `centroid` by 100.  If your locator looks skewed, you should check the point ordering on your quad to make sure it's what you expect.

Once your matrix is correct, getting either an euler or a quaternion is simple:

```
eulers = matrix.getRotation()
quat = matrix.getRotationQuaternion()
```

Check the [docs for TransformationMatrix](https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/PyMel/generated/classes/pymel.core.datatypes/pymel.core.datatypes.TransformationMatrix.html#pymel.core.datatypes.TransformationMatrix) for any more.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Worked like a charm.
I have to do some studies to the Matrix topic. Looks really useful when dealing with this kind of problem.

Comment: You might find the blog post series here useful https://theodox.github.io/2014/bagels_and_coffee.html